# Gulp.js : Is all these JS code needed?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, autoprefixer

I'm trying to install the Autoprefixer using Gulp by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4U0KvAi7NOc

I've installed the NPM thing and Gulp etc, but at 13:51, he creates a Gulp.js file and types in all these code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('autoprefix', function() {
  return gulp.src('css/styles.css')
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

After installing Gulp in my project directory, is it still required to type in all these?

Secondly, in the Gulp.js file I created based on the code above, I get an error in my code editor which says "require is not defined", meaning the code editor doesn't recognize `require` as a JavaScript function.

What should I do?

Comment: What  code editor are you using?  You may need to add a plugin if you are using sublimetext specifically for gulp syntax.

Comment: I just tested with sublimetext and the error message did not show up.  I don't think a plugin is needed.  Other than that the code appears valid to me.  To run the task you should type, 'gulp autoprefix' from the terminal.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver CC. According to google, it seems "require" is a NodeJS thing and it can't be run from the browser or something. Does that mean I need to install it on the server (web hosting)?

Comment: Hi, gulp runs on top of NodeJS  platform. 'require'  is a nodejs inbuilt function. So some editors may not aware of this. And Gulpfile.js is the config file, which describes the tasks to run. Have you tried running this command in console,  'gulp autoprefix' ' ?

Comment: @lokesh-coder : Tks, you mean I just type "npm gulp autoprefix" into my console and I'm ready to use autoprefixer? I looked at Browserify since it can fix the "require" problem, but it's very complicated, and even the Browserify config file doesn't recognize "require". Can "require.js" solve this "require" problem?

Comment: @IlloYonexIllo, first select your directory in console, like C:/projects/current-project/.
#step1: type > `npm install --global gulp`
this will install gulp globally. means you can directly use `gulp <task-name>`
#step2: now run > `gulp autoprefix` in console.
Dont need `npm` in front of the code. Because gulp is now installed gobally
#step3: after running the previous code, if there is no error message in console, check the file 'css/styles.css'.

Comment: Just one additional comment.  Anytime you run 'gulp <task>' from the command line you must in the directory containing your gulp.js file.  In the example above C:/projects/current-project/ would contain gulp.js.